# wx.DirDialog not closing

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Using wxPython version 4.0.1 (pheonix) with python 3.6.5

I use a wxPython DirDialog to allow my user to input a start directory. It correctly selects and populates my "working directory" variable (using GetPath()) but then doesn't ever close the directory dialog prompt box.

I read through the wxPython-user google pages and the only related question I found referred to this as being "intended behavior," implying it would happen later in execution (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wxpython-users/close%7Csort:date/wxpython-users/ysEZK5PVBN4/ieLGEWc6AQAJ).

Mine, however, doesn't close until the entire script has completed running (which takes a fair amount of time), giving me the spinning wheel of death. I have tried a combination of calls to try to force the window to close.

```
app = wx.App()
openFileDialog = wx.DirDialog(None, "Select", curr, wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)
openFileDialog.ShowModal()
working_directory = openFileDialog.GetPath()
openFileDialog.EndModal(wx.CANCEL) #also wx.Close(True) and wx.Destroy()
openFileDialog.Destroy()
openFileDialog=None
```

I have also tried creating a window, passing it as the parent of the DirDialog, and then closing the window and it gives the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which operating system you are on or version of `wx` but in the partial code that you supplied there is no `MainLoop`, which is what was mentioned by Robin Dunn in his answer, in your link.
Try this and see if it works the way you would expect.

```
import wx
from os.path import expanduser
import time

class choose(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Dialog")
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        text = wx.StaticText(panel,-1, "Place holder for chosen directory")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.Show()
        curr = expanduser("~")
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(None, message="Choose a directory", defaultPath = curr,
          style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            text.SetLabel(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()
        b = wx.BusyInfo("I'm busy counting",parent=None)
        wx.Yield()
        for i in range(30):
            time.sleep(1)
        del b


    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app = wx.App()
    choose(None)
    my_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This code is in a method called once from the main loop of my script. The code you supplied and the behavior I get whenever I do something comparable in IDLE all give me the expected behavior. It is when I try to do something more intensive after that the dialog box doesn't close and it gives me a spinning wheel of death.

Comment: I've added a busy function, in an attempt to emulate your situation. Have you tried running the code from the command line rather than IDLE? Do you get the same behaviour? I had to look up what IDLE is, so I have no idea if it is getting in the way or not.

Comment: IDLE is comparable to a command line interactive shell. Both work. It is when I run my script (from the command line) that I have the problem. I suspect that it is because the GUI thread is blocked during execution of the rest of the code.

Comment: I have even tried introducing threading to keep everything separate and am still unable to force the box to close when expected in a script.

Comment: "the Gui thread is blocked" - see my use of `wx.Yield` above, to ensure that the busy message shows up. Read https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks